# how to uncompressed compress image from .ipa file

Tags: php, ipa

I am creating web app demo to create manifest and copy icon image of .ipa file(iPhone application)

I have used below library -
 https://github.com/wbroek/IPA-Distribution

I am succeeded to create manifest and copy icon image of iPhone app  from .ipa to image folder but this image is compress so when i try to open or show this image in web page it give me black image. I search lot but i doesn't get how to uncompressed this image.

Please ,can anyone tell me what is procedure to uncompressed this image and then copy to image folder.

Answer (score 0):

Apps compiled for iOS have their images optimized in some PNG format that is specific to Apple :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1681/_index.html

Simplest fix would be to run xcrun through exec(), if that is an option for you.

Comment: I have install pngcrush library and run below command 

pngcrush -revert-iphone-optimizations icon.png icn1.png

and get below error  While reading icon.png:
  pngcrush caught libpng error:
   incorrect header check



Skipping CgBI chunk.
While reading Icon.png:
  pngcrush caught libpng error:
   IDAT: incorrect header check

Answer (score 0):

While analyzing the task I came to know that Apple compressed all the PNG Images which are not visible in window and Linux machine but visible on mac machine.

To use the PNG files, I have to uncompressed these files but unfortunately there is no API or library available to uncompress such files.

While googling I came across the java desktop application (.jar file) which converts compressed iPhone file to PNG image.

So you have to intergrate that .ja r file in php code

I have written blog on this . [click here](http://www.cuelogic.com/blog/convert-iphone-png-to-standard-png-pngconverter/) to see in detal